# What typeface is used in the EL&U header?

Tags: discussion, design

Which typeface is this?

[image: EL&U header]

How does it get instantiated into the page? I tried looking at the webpage source with Firebug and it just shows up the following HTML tags.

```
<div id="hlogo">
  <a href="/">English Language and Usage</a>
</div>
```

Comment: [Cornbread Ninja says the ampersand is from Baskerville Italic.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/what-font-does-the-site-use/2817#2817)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The title font is [Adobe Caslon Bold](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/adobe-caslon/).

The logo is shown as a CSS sprite of the anchor link inside of the "hlogo" div.

Comment: http://sstatic.net/englishmeta/img/logo.png?v=123

Comment: thanks. the text is "rough-ified", though, right?

Comment: @sibbaldiopsis yes. I didn't design the English site. I contracted a talented designer Alex Charchar for this project. If you love design and typography, you should check out his blog: http://retinart.net A lot of interesting articles there.

Comment: @sibbaldiopsis: I believe the proper term for the treatment is "distressed" type.

Comment: Apparently [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) doesn't guess it correctly.

Comment: (1) What font is the ampersand? It's really pretty. (2) I clicked on the myfonts link and checked out their Central/Eastern European fonts. I had to laugh at their example phrase: *Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép* = "Flood-tolerant drill for mirrors" (in Hungarian).

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty similar to [Caslon Antique](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/grouptype/caslon-antique/) to me, though the ampersand is definitely different.

Edit: Could it be [Letterpress Text](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/chriscostello/letterpress-text/)? Or perhaps [Americanus](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/aerotype/americanus/)?